# Delete directory in java is not deleting directory

Tags: java, zip

I am deleting diretory after zipped the same. I used the following code to make zip and delete.

I am able to do zip and cant delete the folder.

Can anyone point me where I am doing mistake.

Here the code I m using

```
    public class ZipDirectory {

        public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
            zipFolder("d:\\conf2", "d:\\conf2.zip");
          }

          static public void zipFolder(String srcFolder, String destZipFile) throws Exception {
            ZipOutputStream zip = null;
            FileOutputStream fileWriter = null;
            fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(destZipFile);
            zip = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter);

            addFolderToZip("", srcFolder, zip);
            zip.flush();
            zip.close();

            delete(new File(srcFolder));
          }

          static private void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile, ZipOutputStream zip)
              throws Exception {

            File folder = new File(srcFile);
            if (folder.isDirectory()) {
              addFolderToZip(path, srcFile, zip);
            } else {
              byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
              int len;
              FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
              zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));
              while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                zip.write(buf, 0, len);
              }
            }
          }

          static private void addFolderToZip(String path, String srcFolder, ZipOutputStream zip)
              throws Exception {
            File folder = new File(srcFolder);
            for (String fileName : folder.list()) {       
                addFileToZip(path + "/" + folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/" + fileName, zip);        
            }
          }

          static private void delete (File path){
            if( path.exists() ) {
                File[] files = path.listFiles();
                for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                     files[i].delete();                
                }
              }
            path.delete();
          }   

        }
```

Comment: do u have directories in this folder?

Comment: Are you getting any error message or exception?

Comment: Check the return value of `files[i].delete()`. It will be `false` if not successful. Maybe the directory contains sub-directories as @SachinGupta already noted.

Comment: See the first example of `FileVisitor` in Java API doc for how to delete an entire file tree: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html

Comment: You can't delete a directory if it's not empty, This might be one of the reason  why the delete() API failed.

Comment: I don't have sub-directories under this folder.

Comment: @isnot2bad , yes the return shows false only, but I am not having subdirectories. Only having PDF file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please close `FileInputStream` 's instance to make your deletion successful.

please add `in.close()` in `addFileToZip()` method.

Comment: I don't have sub-directories under this folder.

Comment: @Mary.Hansen I have edited my answer, please close `FileInputStream` 's instance.
I think after that It will work.

Answer (score 1):

On taking trace of the delete method it shows the below

07:58:12.734018754           0x2970500         mt.0    Entry        >java/io/File.delete()Z Bytecode method, This = 0xfffc4810

07:58:12.734019108           0x2970500         mt.3    Entry         >java/lang/System.getSecurityManager()Ljava/lang/SecurityManager; Bytecode static method

07:58:12.734019462           0x2970500         mt.9    Exit

07:58:12.734019815           0x2970500         mt.0    Entry         >java/io/File.isInvalid()Z Bytecode method, This = 0xfffc4810

> > On deleting the  file, security manager refuse to delete the file because of already existing file descriptor associated to that. Close the Fileinput stream  to avoid this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are not colling the ZipOutputStream object that you have created. Try replacing following method in you code. Here I have created ZipOutputStrean object in try-with-resource and it worked

```
static public void zipFolder(String srcFolder, String destZipFile) throws Exception {
    try(ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destZipFile)))
    {
        addFolderToZip("", srcFolder, zip);
        zip.flush();
        zip.close();

        delete(new File(srcFolder));
    }
}
```

Comment: Still, it is not deleted the folder.. I copied the method. Any ideas?

Comment: In addFileToZip method of yours, close the FileInputStream object and your problem will be solved.  "in.close(); "